# Laravel: a function is always called on given routes. No middleware is present

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have a Laravel 5.6 route (`/media/collection`) which looks like this:

```php
Route::get('/media/collection', 'frontend\CollectionController@GetMyCollection')
    ->name('collection');
```

The problem is that on every request (to this route ONLY) another function `CollectionController->searchProduct()` is called, which throws an Exception due to a missing keyword (which is a normal behaviour, `searchProduct()` is supposed to throw and exception on a missing keyword).

`CollectionController->GetMyCollection()`'s first row is `dd('Stop right there');`.
I even tried reformatting my route to look like this:

```
Route::get('/media/collection', function() {
  return 'Sample result';
})->name('collection');
```

There is no Middleware that calls `CollectionController->searchProduct()`.

No matter what I try I always get the "no-keyword present" Exception with a `500 Internal Server Error`.

How to find what calls `CollectionController->searchProduct()`?

Comment: Please show your controller for this method. and also `web.php`

Comment: show controller function for this route and base controller which extend CollectionController

Comment: Provide all routes that call `searchProduct` directly or indirectly. Maybe there's another route matching.

Comment: Is there a route defined to `searchProduct` that contains route parameters?